# React + typeScript + bugsnag possible?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, bugsnag

My question : is it possible to integrate bugsnag inside React App witch is using typeScript?

I am currently working on my API call crash/error protect and I heard some good stuff about bugsnag and the rise of 'Unhandled error'.
I don't see any typeScript mention inside the official doc, so I ask my question here to get more information

Answer (score 1):

It looks like BugSnag ships Typescript definitions. Mentioned in [their docs](https://docs.bugsnag.com/platforms/javascript/#typescript-support):

> Type definitions are provided and will be picked up automatically by
>   the TypeScript compiler when you import any of the top-level
>   @bugsnag/* packages.